# 500 sonarqube server error when accessing project.protobuf

Tags: sonarqube

I found an potential issue with SQ 5.6.6.
After i split projects into modules, issue happened and the project on sonarqube server couldn't be use anymore.

Could someone from SonarQube team look into it?

project folder structure:

```
test
  |
   --module1
  |       |
  |       hello.c
  |
  |
   --module2
          |
          hello.c
```

Scenarios:

step1: add sonar-project.properties in test folder without module info and do full analysis. Succeed

```
cat test/sonar-project.properties
sonar.projectKey=com:test
sonar.projectName=test
sonar.analysis.mode=publish
```

step2: split the project into 2 modules by adding  sonar.modules=module1,module2. and add sonar-projects.properties in module1 and module2 folder. Do full analysis again. Succeed.

```
cat test/sonar-project.properties
sonar.projectKey=com:test
sonar.projectName=test
sonar.analysis.mode=publish
sonar.modules=module1,module2

cat test/module1/sonar-project.properties
sonar.projectName=module1

cat test/module2/sonar-project.properties
sonar.projectName=module2
```

Step3: Do full analysis again. Failed and errors as follows. And the project on SonarQube server can't used anymore since https://xx.com/batch/project.protobuf?key=com%3test&issues_mode=true always returned 500 the same as i entered this link in web browser.

looks like, step2 messed up protobuf of SQ server.

Workaround: delete the whole project from sonarQube server

Errors:

```
DEBUG: GET 500 https://xx.com/batch/project.protobuf?key=com%3Atest&issues_mode=true | time=184ms
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 6.160s
INFO: Final Memory: 63M/1603M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.api.config.Settings
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:272)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:112)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:140)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
        at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
        at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:240)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:110)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:72)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.repository.ProjectRepositories
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 500 on https://xx.com/batch/project.protobuf?key=com%3Atest&issues_mode=true
        at org.sonarqube.ws.client.BaseResponse.failIfNotSuccessful(BaseResponse.java:34)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchWsClient.failIfUnauthorized(BatchWsClient.java:99)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchWsClient.call(BatchWsClient.java:69)
        at org.sonar.batch.repository.DefaultProjectRepositoriesLoader.load(DefaultProjectRepositoriesLoader.java:58)
        at org.sonar.batch.repository.ProjectRepositoriesProvider.provide(ProjectRepositoriesProvider.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67)
        ... 37 more
```

Comment: Could you check what error you have in the file `logs/sonar.log` in SonarQube?